# Script and style sheet added from theme edit section in admin panel is not showing on frontend

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

1. Go to admin panel click "content" design->configuration and inside of HTML head cloumns "scripts and style sheets" columns
2. when I add the content and click save, then it is not shown on frontend.
   I checked it using Ctrl + u

I have also cleared caches and checked but still not showing.

Could anyone suggest what could be the problem as I am really stuck and could not get any idea from google regarding this issue.

screenshot
[image]

[image]

[image]